# What are all the special hotkeys in starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently learned that pressing the <kbd>w</kbd> would select all my warpgates, and it changed my life. I also read somewhere that you can cycle through your nexuses with the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key.

What are all the special hotkeys in starcraft 2 (English version) for every race?

<sub>By *special* I mean not the ones used for building and performing actions with your units, as those can be learned by hovering the mouse over the button in-game (but you're welcome to include them in your answer if you like)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full list off all hotkeys [can be found here](http://www.starcraft2freaks.com/starcraft-2-hotkeys-list/), under the keyboard advertisement.

But they are also listed in **Menu** (F10) -> **Options** -> **Hotkeys**, as seen in the next picture.

[image]

**Hint**: You can also set the Grid profile there, so you don't even have to learn the in-game hotkeys.
That profile maps each Grid Command Buttons to rows of keys on your keyboard.

This greatly decreased finger movement and allowed me to increase my APM a bit...

So a Refinery would be: <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>, a Supply Depot: <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>.

Z is then the lower left button, W and E being the second and third button on the first row.

**Source**: http://www.starcraft2freaks.com/how-to-use-starcraft-2-grid-hotkeys/

***Warning***: If you don't have the US keyboard locale installed, the grid profile does not work (it just uses the standard profile although the Grid one is selected in that screen -- it also changes the hotkey for warpgates from <kbd>W</kbd> to <kbd>Y</kbd> among a few others, very messy)

Comment: This has the added benefit that my `a` key is a little broken and kind of comes off in my notebook, very annoying when I'm in the middle of a game

Comment: This is taking some getting used to, specially when using control groups...

Answer (score 1):

Press `Spacebar` to center on the most recent event.