# How does the game decide which building to center on when double-tapping a hotkey bound to multiple separate buildings?

Tags: starcraft-2

Say I have all of my nexuses on hotkey <kbd>4</kbd>.  I double-tap <kbd>4</kbd> -- how does the game decide *which* nexus to center the camera on?  Is there a way to quickly toggle around, centering on each building in a hotkey group in turn?  Or must I always use separate hotkeys for each nexus?

These [two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10542/what-are-all-the-special-hotkeys-in-starcraft-2) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/is-there-a-way-to-set-hotkeys-to-locations-in-starcraft-2) mention <kbd>spacebar</kbd> as another way to cycle around your bases, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Not going to put this as an answer, because I'm not sure it works in all cases:

With Hatches, when multiple of the same type are selected, the first one will be a lighter shade of green, tabbing if I remember correctly swaps through building of the same type. When space is pressed it goes to the selected one.

Comment: I feel screen position hotkeys (F-keys by default) are far superior to any other option for jumping between bases, at least for me.

Comment: I don't have a answer for your question, but if you are looking to cycle through hatcheries or nexuses I suggest using the backspace which is the default for cycling through your bases. The space bar sends your screen to a recent alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are looking for this exactly, but here is my best guess. 
Mkaito may be right. It may very well center on the one closest to where your screen is. I will test this shortly and update my answer.

However, for quickly switching through bases you can use the backspace key or you can move that key in the settings to a more favorable position.

Spacebar is simply for recent alerts.

**Edit** I just tested out the theory. When double clicking your hotkey group it does snap the the building closest to your current screen position. There is no way to toggle through the list, however. Tab does not work nor does spacebar or backspace.

Comment: have you tried double-tapping the hotkey again to toggle through the list?

Comment: That doesn't work, only snaps to the nearest building.

Answer (score 3):

It centers on the one closest to where the camera currently is. Same goes for control groups with units. One thing I haven't experimented with is what happens if a fraction of the control group you're double-tapping is currently on screen. My guess is that it goes the the nearest off-screen entity in that control group, but as I said, that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but my solution is:
after selecting the building group, click the icon for the building you want to centre on. Then click the portrait.

Requires mouse usage unfortunately, and 2 clicks.

Comment: This looks really redundant. Just click approximately where your nexus is at your minimap and doubletap your hotkey. This way you might be lucky and be instantly where you want to be, otherwise you just click 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe that you can toggle through a group of your buildings. Just check the controls options and there should be a button you can use to do so. But definitely, double tapping goes to the closest building.

(Can somebody confirm if there is an option to toggle in the control options?)